# Hibernate mapping confusion

Tags: java, hibernate

The below definition is taken from [Hibernate association mapping tutorial here](http://d12171974.u50.c5.ixwebhosting.com/hibernate_tutorials/Hibernate%20Tutorial%2004.pdf)

**Each book is related to one publisher while one publisher may publish many books.**

I'd represent the above definition the below way in Java

```
class Book
{
  Publisher pub;
}

class Publisher
{
  Set<Book> books;
}
```

---

Question 1. Now I am confused as to why the tutorial says **The association from book to publisher is called a *“many-to-one”* association.** I thought **There is a *"one-to-many"* association between the publisher and the book would have been the right approach.**

Question 2. Below is the hbm for Book. Why shouldn't we declare a one-to-many in the Publisher's hbm mapping. What determines the location for this relationship mapping?

```
<class name="Book" table="BOOK"> 
  <many-to-one name="publisher" class="Publisher" column="PUBLISHER_ID" /> 
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association from `Book` to `Publisher` is **many-to-one** because there can be *many* books per publisher. This is irrelevant to the that fact that `Book` is only aware of its own `Publisher`. The association is to aid Hibernate in understanding the underlying representation.

There is nothing wrong with also declaring a **one-to-many** relationship from `Publisher` to `Book`. You can have both present. It depends on your data model and how you plan on interacting with it.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on whether the relationship is bidirectional.  See section 7.3.2 here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-mapping.

a bidirectional relationship is when you can go from both the parent to the child (i.e. Publisher -> Book) and from child to parent (i.e. Book -> Publisher).  The parent to child is a one-to-many, while the child to parent is a many-to-one.

Note you do not need bidirectional relationships.  The 'right approach' depends exactly on what your application needs.  If you need to only go from pu.lisher to book, you only need a one to many.  If you only need to go from books to publisher, that you just need the many to one.  If you need both, you can have both (i.e. make the relationship bidirectional)/

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Actually both are correct. It depends on the direction of the relationship. Many books belong to one publisher results in a many to one relationship from the book side.

Question 2: If you are interested in a bi-directional relationship then you can actually place  a one to many on one side and a many to one on the other. However, you have to be careful to use the mappedBy attribute to ensure that hibernate knows that its the same relationship being defined from both ends.

Answer (score 1):

A relationship can be unidirectional, or bidirectional.

The way you designed it in your Java code, it's bidirectional. This means that the same physical relationship (materialized by the foreign key) is viewed as two logical relationships :

1. from the book point of view : several books are published by one publisher (ManyToOne)
2. from the publisher point of view : one publisher publishes several books (OneToMany)

The XML mapping you show in your question describes one side of the relationship. But if you want to make it bidirectional, you must also declare the other side. One of the sides is declared as the inverse of the other.

Hibernate gives you the choice : you could have a collection of books in the publisher class (unidirectional one to many), or a publisher reference in the book class (unidirectional many to one), or both (bidirectional one to many/many to one).

Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html) for more details.